# How to add a setter injection injecting a service from a bundle extension

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to make some kind of optional dependency on doctrine orm.
Depending on the configuration, I want "doctrine.orm.entity_manager" to be injected with setter injection to the alsatian_form.form_event_subscriber.extensible service.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class AlsatianFormExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $configFormBundle = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');


        if($configFormBundle['extensible_entity']['enabled']){
            $definition = $container->getDefinition('alsatian_form.form_type.extensible_entity');
            $definition->setPublic(true);
            $definition->addTag('form.type');

            $container->getDefinition('alsatian_form.form_event_subscriber.extensible')
                ->addMethodCall('setEntityManager', array("@doctrine.orm.entity_manager")); // <- here I tried with the same syntax as in YAML configuration files.
        }
    }
}
```

I think it must be a syntax problem, because I receive the string '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager' instead of the entity manager ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#setter-injection) :

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

container->getDefinition('alsatian_form.form_event_subscriber.extensible')
                ->addMethodCall('setEntityManager', array(new Reference("doctrine.orm.entity_manager")));
```

I hope it can help someone.